# Two tones:czt vs fft

Tags: fft

My question is whether the chirp z-transformed is capable of solving two very close tones that an FFT is not capable of solving. I understand that it is possible but I have done tests in Matlab and I cannot get more information from a signal.

The formulation that I have used is the following:$X_k= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n z_k^{-n}$ where $z_k=A W^{-k}$ and $W=e^{\frac{-j2\pi (f_2 - f_1)}{m F_s}}$ and $A=e^{\frac{j2\pi f_1}{F_s}}$ Fs is the frequency sampling, f2 and f1 are the start and final of the interest bandwidth and m is the number of samples.

**Implementation**

```
Fs = 8000;
L = 128;
T = 1/Fs;
t = (0:L-1)*T;
f1=480;
f2=520;
X = sin(2*pi*f1*t) + sin(2*pi*f2*t);
Y = fft(X);
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
figure
plot(f,P1)

f1=480;
f2=520;
X = sin(2*pi*f1*t) + sin(2*pi*f2*t);
m=length(X);
f1 = 100;
f2 =1000;
%Resolucion de 100-1000/128=7Hz 
w = exp(-j*2*pi*(f2-f1)/(m*Fs));
a = exp(j*2*pi*f1/Fs);
Y2=czt(X,m,w,a);
fn = (0:m-1)'/m;
fz = (f2-f1)*fn + f1;

% Resolucion_czt2=fz(2)-fz(1);
hold on
plot(fz,2*abs(Y2/m))
axis([f1 f2 0 inf])
legend({'FFT', 'CZT'})
```

[image: CZT vs FFT]

Comment: Yes, as discussed before: you define where the CZT is sensitive, so it's up to you. To assess what is not working, we'd need to know exactly what you're doing, mathematically. Do you have a formula for us?

Comment: also, why CZT, if you're actually after *tones* – wouldn't that be a case for Goertzel, here?

Comment: Hi Marcus,
My purpose is not to actually analyze tones, I am just doing a test with CZT to understand how it works, so I do not use Goertzel.

I attach my Matlab code in case you find any errors:

Comment: I'll recommend to write exactly the *formula* down of what you're doing, at least once, and then start infering things from that! It's much harder to understand what it's *doing* from its output than from its construction!

Comment: Fs = 8000;               
L = 128;
T = 1/Fs;
t = (0:L-1)*T;
f1=480;
f2=520;
X = sin(2*pi*f1*t) + sin(2*pi*f2*t);
Y = fft(X);
P2 = abs(Y/L); 
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1); 
f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
figure
plot(f,P1)
              
f1=480;
f2=520;
X = sin(2*pi*f1*t) + sin(2*pi*f2*t);
m=length(X);
f1 = 100; f2 =1000; %Resolucion de 100-1000/128=7Hz
w = exp(-j*2*pi*(f2-f1)/(m*Fs));
a = exp(j*2*pi*f1/Fs);

Y2=czt(X,m,w,a);
fn = (0:m-1)'/m;
fz = (f2-f1)*fn + f1;
Resolucion_czt2=fz(2)-fz(1);
hold on
plot(fz,2*abs(Y2/m))
axis([f1 f2 0 inf])

Comment: sorry, that code in a comment is completely illegible, especially as `*` get converted to formatting. Honestly, I also don't think your code helps us any further. Again, the question is about the CZT and not about how matlab implements it, or how you use matlabs implementation. So, get formulating.

Comment: The formulation that I have used is the following:
$X_k= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n z_k^{-n}$
where $z_k=A W^{-k}$
and $W=e^{\frac{-j2\pi (f_2 - f_1)}{m F_s}}$ and $A=e^{\frac{j2\pi f_1}{F_s}}$
Fs is the frequency samping, f2 and f1 are the start and final of the intererst bandwidth and m is the number of samples.

Comment: Ah, cool! (Could you add that to your question as is? It really explains much about the problems you're facing!) But you *know* the two tones you want to detect exactly, right?

Comment: In Matlab I have generated two sines of 470 and 530 Hz with a sampling frequency of 8000Hz and a length of 128 samples. If I do the normal FFT the spectral resolution is 62.5 Hz so the two tones cannot be distinguished.
In the case of the CZT, I have chosen f1 = 100 and f2 = 1000 with the same number of samples so the resolution is 1000-100 / 128 = 7Hz. The resolution should be enough to distinguish the tones but I can't see it.

Comment: I don't understand why you state this *should* be able to resolve this? Where does that come from? (Note: I really don't see it, but I might just be missing it?) (also, all your comment about what yo do should be part of your question, not just "hidden" somewhere in the comments!)

Comment: I have read several papers that say they are capable of solving it. my final question is: is this possible? it is possible to distinguish between two tones using CZT when in FFT it is not possible to?

Comment: It's possible, you're just not appropriately parameterizing it, because you just plug in numbers to formulas you took from papers without *understanding* what they do, it seems! So, coming back: **where** specifically does it come from that a $W$ with the frequency difference will deliver good separation? Can we please work with the sources you have instead of unclear claims?

Comment: I am exactly after the same answer. I whant to know if there is a way to estimate how much resolution is possible to get using czt from a previously sampled signal. Best regards